# Jquery Ajax not able to overwrite the span class

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am getting the value in the script which i posted below the ajax function

```
    $("select#variant1").change(function(){
    $("#storemidet").hide();
    $("#custememibx").hide();
    $("#onprice11").html("Loading...");

    var vid = $("select#variant1 option:selected").attr('value');
    var id = $("select#model1 option:selected").attr('value');
    var cid = $("select#ecity option:selected").val();
    $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>common/loadonprice", {id:id,vid:vid,cid:cid}, function(data){
    $("#onprice1").focus();
    $("#onroadprice1").val(data);

    $("#onprice1").html([data.toString()]);
    });

    });
<li class="mvprice">Rs. <span id="onprice1">-</span></li>
```

- I am getting the value of onprice1 value in the ajax, but not
  overwriting my html above in the span-->onprice1. Can anyone help with this

Comment: what is the response of data in your ajax request?

Comment: its just a number eg:492165

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with:

```
$("span#onprice1").html(data.toString());
```

instead of

```
$("#onprice1").html([data.toString()]);
```